# Git diff is not showing absolute differences between files on different branches (raw differences across all commits)

Tags: git

I have two branches. `Master` and `A`. I've made changes on `A`, committed them. Made more changes on `A` and committed them. And done this several times. I need to view all the changes between `Master` and `A`. I've been using `git diff` to try to check that however, I'm pretty sure it's only showing me the most recent commit changes on `A`. I've manually inspected the files and I know there are more changes and when I do use `VCS/git/compare with branch` feature on PyCharm I can see the full changes.

The following commands I've tried are

`git diff master`
`git diff A..master`
`git diff A...master`

Which only shows the most recent changes.

Comment: And you are absolutely sure the branches are on the revisions you assume they are, right? Like, master hasn't moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember that `git diff` only ever really compares *two specific commits*,<sup>1</sup> or one commit to your current index or work-tree.  So when you run `git diff A..master` or `git diff A...master`, you're choosing the two commits.

You can also use `git diff A master`.  This does exactly the same thing as `git diff A..master`.  It picks the commit to which the branch name `A` points, to hold on the left side, and the commit to which the branch name `master` points, to hold on the right side.  Then it compares the left and right sides.

Remember that each commit represents a *full snapshot of all of your files*.  Assume for a moment that your commits contain a `main.py` and a `README.py`.  Whether or not you just changed `main.py` or `README.md` or not, *new* a `git commit` run *right now* will snapshot the version of `main.py` and `README.md` that are in the *index* right now.  (Git also calls this the *staging area*, so the terms *index* and *staging area* mean the same thing.)  Git makes the commits from the index / staging-area contents, not from the work-tree contents, which is why Git makes you run `git add` all the time: that copies updated files back into the index / staging-area.

This means that if you modify `main.py` and `git add` and commit it, then modify it again to change it *back* and modify `README.md`, add all of these, and commit again, comparing the commit from two steps ago to now will show *no* difference to `main.py`—the version you just committed matches the one from two steps ago—and one change to `README.md`.

Use `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` to get `git log` to draw a crude ASCII diagram of your commits, with the branch name annotations showing which particular commit each branch-name identifies.  That will tell you which two *commits* are getting compared when you run `git diff A master` or `git diff A..master`.

Note that the three-dot notation means something quite different: `A...master` means *find a merge base commit for `A` and `master`, then diff that commit vs the one identified by `master`*.  That is, this is the same as `git diff $(git merge-base A master) master`.

Listing just one commit, as in `git diff master`, tells Git to compare that commit to your current work-tree.  In this case the work-tree is always on the right side of the diff.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, in some situations, you can get `git diff` to run multiple diffs, two commits at a time, and then *combine* them into a *combined diff*, but this only really works with merge commits and their multiple parents.  The combined diff subtracts away files that match any one parent, and mostly just shows where the merge did or would have had conflicts.

<sup>2</sup>In this case, since you aren't naming two commits, there is no easy way to swap the two operands.  Fortunately `git diff` allows the `-R` (Reverse) option to swap the left and right sides, if you need that for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for all the insight! So is there no way to show the full raw difference between the same file in 2 different branches?

Comment: `git diff <commit1> <commit2> -- <name/of/file>` does the same thing, but tells `git diff` to display just the one file. As before, *branch names* aren't very important here; what matters is which two *commits* you select. A branch (often/usually) contains many commits; the name simply selects the *last* commit on the branch.